# heroku-accounts plugin doesn't recognize `heroku accounts:set` command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to use heroku accounts for working and personal separately.
So, I installed heroku plugin for it.

```
% heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git
Installing git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git... done

% heroku accounts:add personal
Uninstalling deprecated ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin...Done. Use https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts instead.That account already exists.
```

First command seems to run properly, but after that the `accounts:*` commands become unavailable.

```
% heroku accounts:set personal
 !    `accounts:set` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

% heroku accounts:add personal
 !    `accounts:add` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: deprecated ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin is installed.

you can use this version: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts